# Why Java Collections.asLifoQueue is NOT LIFO?

Tags: java, collections

Please see the snippet below:

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Deque<String> dq = new ArrayDeque<String>(5);
        dq.add("java");
        dq.add("c");
        dq.add("c++");
        dq.add("unix");
        dq.add("perl");
        Queue<String> q = Collections.asLifoQueue(dq);
        System.out.println("returned queue is: "+q.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
returned queue is: [java, c, c++, unix, perl]
```

Shouldn't the output be the following instead?:

```
[perl, unix, c++, c, java]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#asLifoQueue(java.util.Deque))'s the javadoc for `asLifoQueue`. This is what it says:

> Returns a view of a Deque as a Last-in-first-out (Lifo) Queue. Method
>   add is mapped to push, remove is mapped to pop and so on. This view
>   can be useful when you would like to use a method requiring a Queue
>   but you need Lifo ordering.

So, it gives you a LIFO `view` from the existing queue, meaning the existing queue remains as is but new method calls follow `LIFO` standards.

Now, in your example, if I call `add` again, after getting `LIFO` queue, it gets translated into `push` and hence, the element gets added at the top, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     Deque<String> dq = new ArrayDeque<String>(5);
        dq.add("java");
        dq.add("c");
        dq.add("c++");
        dq.add("unix");
        dq.add("perl");
        Queue<String> q = Collections.asLifoQueue(dq);
        q.add("test");
        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(q.remove());
        }
 }
```

It prints 'test' first when the above gets executed.

Comment: Thanks. javadoc is kinda misleading. I thought the original input will be organized by LIFO after calling this method. Thank you for taking time to answer my question. Solute!

Comment: @XGR thanks for the feedback. Could you please upvote the answer or mark it as accepted if you think it has helped you?

Answer (score 2):

The `Collections.asLifeQueue` method doesn't affect elements already in the original collection. The sample code is mixing operations on the original collection, which has FIFO semantics, with the wrapped collection, which has LIFO semantics. That's why it's not working as you expect.

To get the effect you want, wrap the original collection immediately after its creation, and then perform all operations on the wrapper:

```
    Queue<String> q = Collections.asLifoQueue(new ArrayDeque<>());
    q.add("java");
    q.add("c");
    q.add("c++");
    q.add("unix");
    q.add("perl");
    System.out.println("returned queue is: "+q.toString());
```

This gives your expected output:

```
returned queue is: [perl, unix, c++, c, java]
```